# How do I set multiple folder in SBT's `javaSource`?

Tags: scala, sbt

How do I set multiple folders for SBT's `javaSource` ? In [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html) I see how I can specify multiple folders for `unmanagedJars` which has type of `sbt.TaskKey[sbt.Keys.Classpath]` where as `javaSource` has type `sbt.SettingKey[java.io.File]`. But I couldn't come up with way of doing it for javaSource :(

My best shot was this:

```
sourceDirectories in Test ++= Seq(
    "cucumber/java", "integration/java", "selenium/src", "unit")
  .map(value => baseDirectory.value / "test" / value),
```

But after generating IDEA config using `gen-idea` none of test directories were marked as test :(

Comment: Given the type `SettingKey[File]` you won't be able to have multiple folders in `javaSource`. I seem to think you don't need it -- you seem to be asking about how to set up `gen-idea` so it uses the folders as test folders. Is that correct? I'd change the title then as at the moment, it's a yes/no question and the answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to be setting `unmanagedSourceDirectories`; see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Classpaths.html